# How to Limit the characters size of chip of angular-material mat chips?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular material  mat-chips to implement the label's management feature. When I use maxLength validator property, It's checking the number of chips i'e., number of labels.
But I want to show error message when the customer enters 20 characters of label or chip.
I want to restrict the customer entering 20 characters for a chip or label.

Any suggestions.......

Answer (score 2):

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aidmcx)

you can use `maxLength` attribute on input

```
   <input placeholder="New fruit..."
               [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
               [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
               [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
               (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)"
                maxlength=20
               (input)="onChangeValue($event.target.value)" 
        >
```

Comment: Thanks for updating. Can you try the same thing with reactive forms and with maxlength validator.